# R:how to interpret which of the two variable is a stronger predictor in regression modeling in R?

Tags: r, multiple-regression

to compare the effect of the two variables I have standardized the two variables in the model I built. However I am not sure how I can interpret the effect and decide which one is a stronger predictor of `mtld` when the other is controlled for.

```
summary(result1)
summary(lm(mtld ~ scale(mwl) + scale(prof), data = mtld_mwl))


> summary(result1)

Call:
lm(formula = mtld ~ mwl + prof, data = mtld_mwl)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-48.676 -19.357  -3.539  11.346 142.828 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -8.4822    23.1455  -0.366 0.714811    
mwl          13.2935     5.5458   2.397 0.018443 *  
prof          0.3593     0.1015   3.539 0.000619 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 27.18 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1846,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1678 
F-statistic: 10.98 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: 5.026e-05


Call:
lm(formula = mtld ~ scale(mwl) + scale(prof), data = mtld_mwl)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-48.676 -19.357  -3.539  11.346 142.828 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   57.764      2.718  21.253  < 2e-16 ***
scale(mwl)     6.653      2.776   2.397 0.018443 *  
scale(prof)    9.822      2.776   3.539 0.000619 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 27.18 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1846,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1678 
F-statistic: 10.98 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: 5.026e-05
```

Comment: This belongs on CrossValidated rather than stack overflow. However, to just briefly address your question, the prof variable has the bigger effect. A one standard deviation increase in prof results in an estimated increase of 9.82 units of whatever your dependent variable mtld is measured as. Conversely, a one standard deviation change in your independent variable mwl, results in a smaller change in the dependent variable of 'only' 6.65. **However**, please note that using standardized regression coefficients is generally not considered to be good statistical practice.

Comment: Do you know how to do this without using R? I'm not sure they fact that you are using R is really relevant at all here. Interpretation of model results is really a matter of statistics, not programming. And it's unclear exactly what your definition of "stronger predictor" is. This doesn't seem like a programming question that's suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also notice that your t/p-values are identical in the two cases - in this case using standardized variables isn't really telling you anything about `mwl` and `prof` that you didn't already know - the intercept is more interpretable  though.

Comment: @Neal On the contrary, the coefficient estimates for the standardized regressors do provide useful new information.  (Of course the t and p values will be the same, because the standardization merely amounts to changing the units of measurement.)

Comment: Could you elaborate? I thought it only changed the units?

Comment: @Neal That's what I said.  The thing is, you cannot know how the coefficients will change until you actually do change their units.  This amounts either to regressing with the standardized variables or adjusting the estimated coefficients based on the standard deviations of the original variables (which is information not normally included in regression output).

Comment: I thought the ordering / relative magnitude of the standardized coefficients is the same as the t-statistics though - maybe not though.

Comment: @Neal I don't think that's always the case.  In this circumstance, because the SEs of the coefficients are the same, it happens that the t-values will be proportional to the betas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71251/discussion-between-neal-fultz-and-whuber).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by strong predictor. Generally you look at a model's predictive ability rather than that of a variable within the model. You could run one model with only mwl and one with only prof and compare the two, but it doesn't really make sense to try to work out which of the two is a better predictor when the other is being controlled for. If you want to know which of the variables has greater influence on Y, then that's do-able.

Fully agree with Tifu's comment - that's how you'd interpret your second model, but it's best to avoid regressions using standardised variables. You can get the same result by running your first regression and multiplying the estimated coefficients by the standard deviations of the variable. This gives you two directly comparable number that effectively show how much each of the two explanatory variables have actually impacted your dependent variable.

One other thing you can do is put the explanatory variables in logs. The two coefficients are then the elasticities of Y with respect to X1 and X2 - not sure what field you're working in but it's a very common concept to look at in economics in particular. In short, they show the responsiveness of Y to a given change in the explantory variable (specifically, the percentage change in Y resulting from a 1% change in Xi).

I don't think there's any single right answer so others are likely to have alternative ideas, but that's where I'd start. Would also echo the comments - this is much more of a stats question, so you'll get better responses on cross validated.

Comment: Can you comment/provide a reference on why "it's best to avoid regressions using standardised variables"?  For reasons of interpretability?

Comment: I suppose it's a matter of opinion and there may be situations where it makes sense, but I'd argue that wherever you can achieve the same result in multiple ways, it's best to go for the one that preserves the raw data as long as possible. If nothing else, the unstandardised regression results are likely to be of interest to yourself or someone else reading your work at some point, and this way you've got them there ready.

Comment: The model using standardized regressors is the same as the original--standardization merely changes the units of measurement.  Standardization indeed is a conventional and long-standing way to assess and compare individual regressors in a linear regression model.  This approach is so conventional, in fact, that many scientific communities simply refer to the resulting coefficients as the "betas" (at least when the response is also standardized, too).  cc @BenBolker